# Getting ImportError: cannot import name multiarray using Anaconda2 in Wndows

Tags: python, windows, numpy, anaconda, python-import

Previously I didn't have the following problem, it just happened all of a sudden yesterday morning! I tried to update numpy, I tried to uninstall it and then re install it again, I also tried installing a new version, but all of them give me this exact error.

Here is the whole error log :

```
2016-04-06 10:36:57 [20160406-103655-657c] [WARNING] Parse Folder (train/val) unrecognized output: Traceback (most recent call last):
2016-04-06 10:36:57 [20160406-103655-657c] [WARNING] Parse Folder (train/val) unrecognized output: File "T:\DIGITS-master\tools\parse_folder.py", line 8, in <module>
2016-04-06 10:36:57 [20160406-103655-657c] [WARNING] Parse Folder (train/val) unrecognized output: import requests
2016-04-06 10:36:57 [20160406-103655-657c] [WARNING] Parse Folder (train/val) unrecognized output: File "L:\Anaconda2\lib\site-packages\requests\__init__.py", line 58, in <module>
2016-04-06 10:36:57 [20160406-103655-657c] [WARNING] Parse Folder (train/val) unrecognized output: from . import utils
2016-04-06 10:36:57 [20160406-103655-657c] [WARNING] Parse Folder (train/val) unrecognized output: File "L:\Anaconda2\lib\site-packages\requests\utils.py", line 12, in <module>
2016-04-06 10:36:57 [20160406-103655-657c] [WARNING] Parse Folder (train/val) unrecognized output: import cgi
2016-04-06 10:36:57 [20160406-103655-657c] [WARNING] Parse Folder (train/val) unrecognized output: File "L:\Anaconda2\lib\cgi.py", line 50, in <module>
2016-04-06 10:36:57 [20160406-103655-657c] [WARNING] Parse Folder (train/val) unrecognized output: import mimetools
2016-04-06 10:36:57 [20160406-103655-657c] [WARNING] Parse Folder (train/val) unrecognized output: File "L:\Anaconda2\lib\mimetools.py", line 6, in <module>
2016-04-06 10:36:57 [20160406-103655-657c] [WARNING] Parse Folder (train/val) unrecognized output: import tempfile
2016-04-06 10:36:57 [20160406-103655-657c] [WARNING] Parse Folder (train/val) unrecognized output: File "L:\Anaconda2\lib\tempfile.py", line 32, in <module>
2016-04-06 10:36:57 [20160406-103655-657c] [WARNING] Parse Folder (train/val) unrecognized output: import io as _io
2016-04-06 10:36:57 [20160406-103655-657c] [WARNING] Parse Folder (train/val) unrecognized output: File "T:\Caffe\Build\X64\RELEASE\pycaffe\caffe\io.py", line 1, in <module>
2016-04-06 10:36:57 [20160406-103655-657c] [WARNING] Parse Folder (train/val) unrecognized output: import numpy as np
2016-04-06 10:36:57 [20160406-103655-657c] [WARNING] Parse Folder (train/val) unrecognized output: File "L:\Anaconda2\lib\site-packages\numpy\__init__.py", line 180, in <module>
2016-04-06 10:36:57 [20160406-103655-657c] [WARNING] Parse Folder (train/val) unrecognized output: from . import add_newdocs
2016-04-06 10:36:57 [20160406-103655-657c] [WARNING] Parse Folder (train/val) unrecognized output: File "L:\Anaconda2\lib\site-packages\numpy\add_newdocs.py", line 13, in <module>
2016-04-06 10:36:57 [20160406-103655-657c] [WARNING] Parse Folder (train/val) unrecognized output: from numpy.lib import add_newdoc
2016-04-06 10:36:57 [20160406-103655-657c] [WARNING] Parse Folder (train/val) unrecognized output: File "L:\Anaconda2\lib\site-packages\numpy\lib\__init__.py", line 8, in <module>
2016-04-06 10:36:57 [20160406-103655-657c] [WARNING] Parse Folder (train/val) unrecognized output: from .type_check import *
2016-04-06 10:36:57 [20160406-103655-657c] [WARNING] Parse Folder (train/val) unrecognized output: File "L:\Anaconda2\lib\site-packages\numpy\lib\type_check.py", line 11, in <module>
2016-04-06 10:36:57 [20160406-103655-657c] [WARNING] Parse Folder (train/val) unrecognized output: import numpy.core.numeric as _nx
2016-04-06 10:36:57 [20160406-103655-657c] [WARNING] Parse Folder (train/val) unrecognized output: File "L:\Anaconda2\lib\site-packages\numpy\core\__init__.py", line 14, in <module>
2016-04-06 10:36:57 [20160406-103655-657c] [WARNING] Parse Folder (train/val) unrecognized output: from . import multiarray
2016-04-06 10:36:57 [20160406-103655-657c] [WARNING] Parse Folder (train/val) unrecognized output: ImportError: cannot import name multiarray
2016-04-06 10:36:57 [20160406-103655-657c] [ERROR] Parse Folder (train/val) task failed with error code 1
```

Basically what happened is that, I'm trying to port DIGITS, a deep learning front-end which incorporates Caffe to Windows.

At first the part of the application that is now giving me the import error, used to work just fine and another section of the app wasn't working, so I tried to fix that and that was fixed by the way, and all of a sudden I realized the first working section doesn't work any more! and I didn't even do anything to those sections code.

I need to add that I'm not a Python developer, and I only have some basic understanding of the language and its syntax. The changes that I am making are mostly substituting path strings (converting the Linux based paths to their equivalent windows ones, nothing fancy here.) and printing and logging some messages, that's all.

I tried some solutions that I mentioned earlier but no luck yet. For those who are interested here is the [DIGITS group question](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/digits-users/U1DRXupJs2Q).

Currently I am using `Anaconda2-4.0.0-Windows-x86_64.exe` (the latest version and I installed it for all users.) on a win7 machine. Before that I had `Anaconda2-2.4.1-Windows-x86_64.exe`.

Comment: Check that you have a recent version of `numpy`.  If you have several versions of Python installed with numpy, check that you are picking-up the correct one.  Check your PYTHONPATH environment variable for stray versions.

Comment: @cdarke: there is only one version of python installed. 
in the Path variable , there are 
`L:\Anaconda2\python.exe;`
`;L:\Anaconda2;`
`L:\Anaconda2\Scripts`
`;L:\Anaconda2\Library\bin`
and what should be in PYTHONPATH? the path to python.exe? 
I have a user environment variable (PYTHONPATH) which has a path like this : `T:\Caffe\Build\x64\Release\pycaffe`

Comment: PYTHONPATH is the path to Python modules, and this can get seriously messed-up if several versions of Python are installed.  Obviously not the case here.  It would appear that the version of `numpy` is not compatible with the rest of your code.  I can't go any further with this because I don't know Anaconda.  Sorry.

Comment: @Cdarke: Thanks buddy , I appreciate your time and help ;)